# Travis-CI, how to get committer_email, author_name, within after_script command

Tags: testing, github, travis-ci

I know committer_email, author_name, and load of other variables are part of the notification event. Is it possible to get access to them in earlier events like before_script, after_script?

I would like to get access of the information and add it directly to my test results. Having build information, test result information, and github repo information in the same file would be great.

Comment: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables?

Comment: I looked at the environment variables but author and email are not there.

Comment: You can easily extract them via `export COMMITTER_EMAIL="$(git log -1 $TRAVIS_COMMIT --pretty="%aE")"` ([arguments for `--pretty`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables))

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you!!! For anyone else looking for the same, here is a good page with git log [pretty formats help](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)

Comment: Yeah, that link is what I meant to link to, but failed to copypaste properly :v

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can extract committer e-mail, author name, etc. to environment variables using [`git log` with `--pretty`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats), e.g.

```
export COMMITTER_EMAIL="$(git log -1 $TRAVIS_COMMIT --pretty="%cE")"
export AUTHOR_NAME="$(git log -1 $TRAVIS_COMMIT --pretty="%aN")"
```

On Travis one'd put this in the [`before_install` or `before_script`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle) stage.

`TRAVIS_COMMIT` environment variable is [provided by default](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables).